# Disable auto-log-off feature on Windows Server 2012R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, login, logoff

I have 2 PCs, 1 is Windows Server 2012 R2, 1 is Windows 7 Pro. Both control by company's group policy, I access them by Remote Desktop.
On Windows 7, I can start downloading some files (10GB) from Google Drive and leave it till it done, or copy/move some files from one partion to other and leave it there, go to bed and get it done by about tommorow.
On Windows Server 2012 R2, if I leave it (disconnect remote desktop session) I will be automatically log-off by 10 minutes later, and the download/copy/move process will be terminated. 
How can I disable this automatically-log-off feature on my Windows Server PC? Or what's the policy name that handle this feature, so I can ask my IT Dept to customize it?

Comment: This is not a policy, but a configuration on the RD Server. Still, it's called "Active session limit". It's a pretty standard configuration, easy to find with Google ;)

Comment: @curropar I've set it, but still no work! :( the move-process still got stopped and i've been logged off from server https://imgur.com/a/EiGK0Ol

Comment: I've probably not expressed it correctly: this is a set up on the server side, managed by the server administrator. Plus the setup you need is not the one you've selected, but the following.

Comment: @curropar : i've set 5 settings in that image to "never", still got logged off :(

Comment: @curropar : currently, I'm having to have an alarm , for reconnect to server every 14minutes.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer!    My guess is you're doing this in your client, the one you're running the RDP client, but this has been set up at the server level, and that overrules your client. Or if you're doing it at the server, local policies are overruled by Group Policies. So it's up to the server administrator to modify it.