# Best way to Sync files from Windows server 2012 R2 to another Windows server 2012 R2 with only local admin privilege

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012-r2, synchronization, windows-server-backup

My IT dept give me 2 servers (Windows server 2012 R2), the first one have 4TB data, the 2nd one have an empty 5TB partition.
I have admin privilege on both servers.
I have to move all data from server-1 to server-2.
While moving (may take some days - idk) my team member still access to server-1 to edit/create new files.
I can't use DFS.
When I simply open Windows Explorer and do `<c-c> <c-v>` the server kicked me out and kill copy process after 15 minutes (I [did try](https://serverfault.com/questions/908167/disable-auto-log-off-feature-on-windows-server-2012r2) prevent this but anything works).
When I use [Toucan](https://github.com/PortableApps/Toucan) to sync file, it got kicked out like Windows Explorer.
**So, for you pro system admin, when you have to do my task with my privilege, what will you do?**

Comment: Copy the files to a hard drive, send it to the destination, copy it to the other server. Or use Resilio Sync.

Comment: Might try freefilesync. It's easier to use than figuring out a robocopy command and if it fails will let you rescan.

Comment: Do you have access to another machine on the same network, one that won't log you out?  You could do the copy from there.  Or you could use `psexec` (available from the MS web site) with `-s` and `-d` to start a command line running in system context on one of the machines, that will keep running even after you've logged out, and use robocopy.  Awkward though.  The *correct* solution is to get that absurd group policy changed.

Comment: @tim both servers is VM, so I can't do your suggest.

Comment: @HarryJohnston : I've try with `psexec` but got this error, could you give me a hint?   
C:\Users\longnx\Downloads\PSTools>PsExec64.exe \\10.133.28.55 ipconfig

PsExec v2.2 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Couldn't access 10.133.28.55:
The network path was not found.

Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on 10.133.28.55.

Comment: @Luke both of my suggestions work fine on a virtual server. Map the disk to your local PC, plug in a hard drive, copy files to it, send to destination, reverse the process. Resilio Sync would work fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest ROBOCOPY, more information here:

[robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy)

Use /z so if the transfer is interrupted it can be resumed.

With some other good references:

[Here](http://blog.gudge.com/2013/06/file-copy-over-windows-networks-with.html?m=1)
And
[Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx)

Then to fix the issue of 15 minutes log out, one suggestion would be to run this as a scheduled task. That way it runs as a background process and doesn't require an interactive user session to keep running. This page has a nice tutorial about setting that up and as per the article you can have it record its progress and status to a log file so you can see how it is progressing - as well as checking the scheduled task status.  See:

[Here](http://caughtinpixels.com/how-to-create-a-backup-script-using-robocopy/)

As per the article, robocopy is a command line tool and perhaps not as intuative as gui sync tools out there. However it does one thing and does it well and it is from Microsoft, so doesn't require you to install any third party tools which may not be approved by your information security team.

Hope that helps.

Comment: How will this prevent the server from logging the OP out after fifteen minutes?

Comment: Good point, updated.